# How does proc stats work

Tags: linux, shell, linux-kernel

I have done a lot of reading and testing of the proc directory in OS's using the Linux kernel. I have been using Linux myself for many years now, but I needed to get into more details for a small private project. Specifically how the stat files work. I knew the basics, but not enough to create actual calculations with the data in them.

The problem is that the files in proc does not seem to contain what they should, not according to what I have read vs. my tests. 
For example: the CPU line in the root stat file should contain the total uptime for the CPU times the amount of cores (and/or amount of CPU's) in jiffies. So to get the system uptime, you would have to add each number in the row to each other, divide by the number of cores/CPU's and again divide by whatever a jiffie is defined to be on that particular system. At least this is the formula that I keep finding when searching this subject. If this was true, then the result should be equal to the first number in /proc/uptime? But this is not the case, and I have tested this on several machines with different amount of cores, both 32bit and 64bit systems. I can never get these two to match up.

Also the stat file for each pid have an uptime part (part 21 I think it was). But I cannot figure out what this number should be matched against to calculate a process uptime in seconds. So far what I have read, it should contain the total cpu jiffies as they was when the process was started. So if this is true, then one would simply substract this from the current total cpu jiffies and divide this with whatever a jiffie is on that system? But again, I cannot seam to get this to add up to reality.

Then there is the problem with finding out what a jiffie is. I found a formula where /proc/stat was used together with /proc/uptime and some dividing with the amount of cores/CPU's to get that number. But this does not work. And I would not expect it to when the values of those two files does not add up, like mentioned in my first problem above. I did however come up with a different approach. Simply reading the first line of /proc/stat twice within a second. Then I could just compare and see how many jiffies the system had added in that second and divide that with the number of cores. This works on normal Linux systems, but it fails on Android in most cases. Android is constantly attaching/detaching cores depending on needs, which means that it differs how much you have to divide with. It is no problem as long as the core count matches both reads, but if one core goes active during the second read, it does not work.

And last. I do not quite get the part by dividing by amount of cores. If each core writes all of it's work time and idle time to the total line in /proc/stat, then it would make sense as that line would actually contain the total uptime times the amount of cores. But if this was true then each of the cpu lines would add up to the same number, but they don't. This means that dividing by amount of cores should provide an incorrect result. But that would also mean that cpu monitor tools are making calculation errors, as they all seam to use this method.

Example:

**/proc/stat**

```
cpu  20455737 116285 4584497 104527701 1388173 366 102373 0 0 0
cpu0 4833292 5490 1413887 91023934 1264884 358 94250 0 0 0
cpu1 5785289 47944 1278053 4439797 45015 1 4235 0 0 0
cpu2 4748431 20922 926839 4552724 33455 2 2745 0 0 0
cpu3 5088724 41928 965717 4511246 44819 3 1141 0 0 0
```

The lines cpu0, cpu1, cpu2 and cpu3 does not add up to the same total result. This means that using the total result of the general cpu line divided by 4 should be incorrect.

**/proc/uptime**

```
1503361.21 3706840.53
```

All of the above output was taken from a system that should be using clock ticks of 100. Now if you take the result of the general cpu line, divide that with 100 and then with 4 (amount of cores), you will not get the result of the uptime file.

And if you take the result of the general cpu line, divide that with the uptime from /proc/uptime and then with 4 (amount of cores), you will not get the 100 that is this kernels clock ticks.

So why is nothing adding up as it should? How do I get the clock ticks of a kernel, even on systems that attaches/detaches cores constantly? How to I get the total real uptime of a process? How do I get the real uptime from /proc/stat?

Comment: sample code, current outputs, notes about problems. This question can probably be rewritten in 10 lins or so. Please don't expect us to reinvent your algorithm. Good luck.

Comment: I don't have any algorithm. All of these calculations should be quite simple, posted all over the web, and I did write them here. They just don't give the expected result, which I have also given quite detailed example about. I am not looking for anyone to write any algorithms, I just asked for someone who can point out how the data in these files work as the information that I have found so far, seams incorrect.

Comment: This sort of question is out-of-scope for StackOverflow.S.O. is about helping people solve their real-coding problems. By showing the work you have done and characterizing the unexpected output as a bug, people may be willing to help you. Good luck.

Comment: This is not a problem related to any specific language. Whether I make this in Bash, Python, Java, C/C++, Assembly or something else does not really mater. All will use the data from those files, which is where the problem lies. So again, there is no code examples, because I cannot make any code when I can't figure out how this data should be handled to get a correct result. Until now, I have made manual calculations on paper based on output from those files. You want me to scan my notes? You don't create code of nothing, you make a plan first.  Part one of mine, figure out this data.

Comment: hey @shellter, why don't you just let other people decide for them self what they wish to help with? And maybe while you'r add it, just keep your mouth shut if you don't have anything to contribute? No wonder this site is dying. If this is the kind of answer that people get from asking questions, they will simply just stay away and find help elsewhere next time they need it.

Answer (score 2):

*(This answer is based on the 4.0 kernel.)*

The first number on each line of `/proc/stat` is the total time which each CPU has spent executing non-"nice" tasks in user mode. The second is the total time spent executing "nice" tasks in user mode.

Naturally, there will be random variations across CPUs. For example, the processes running on one CPU may make more syscalls, or slower syscalls, than those running on another CPU. Or one CPU may happen to run more "nice" tasks than another.

The first number in `/proc/uptime` is the "monotonic boot time" -- the amount of time which has passed since the system was last booted (including time which passed while the system was suspended). The second number is the total amount of time which all CPUs have spent idling.

There is also a task-specific `stat` file for each PID in the corresponding subdirectory under `/proc`. This one starts with a PID number, a name in brackets, and a state code (represented by a character). The 19th number after that is the start time of the process, in ticks.

All of this information is not very hard to find simply by browsing the Linux source code. I recommend you clone a local copy of Linus' repo and use grep to find the details you need. As a tip, the process-specific files in `/proc` are implemented in `fs/proc/base.c`. The `/proc/stat` file which you asked about is implemented in `fs/proc/stat.c`. `proc/uptime` is implemented in `fs/proc/uptime.c`.

`man proc` is also a good source of information.